# Windows EFS encryption + password protection?

Tags: windows-10, encryption, user-accounts, password-protection, efs

I would like to encrypt files / folders in Windows with EFS. In addition — because EFS alone still leaves the files / folders unprotected in case an adversary managers to access my Windows profile — I would like to password-protect those files / folders. But how? On my own, private PC, where I can create any number of (administrator and of course normal) users. I thought of EFS-encrypting the according files / folders under *another* user of mine, then switching again back to my default user account where I'd now of course be excluded from access to those files / folders. From the other user (used for encryption), however, I imported the EFS certificate into my default user account to regain access. But to no avail: I still I couldn't open those files.

**Please tell me: is there a way to achieve what I tried to do with** (preferrably *native*) **Windows tools like EFS + certificates or other solutions** (excluding  Bitlocker, which is only good to encrypt whole drives >30GB)? And possibly **in an **easier** way** than I described, e.g. like transferring access to another (administrator?) user of mine which subsequently requires other users to enter a password to open if that's possible way to go? Or anything else, please? If not Windows-native, then at least available from the File Explorer context menu?

> *Bonus question: although I was not able to open the above-mentioned files / folders, I was very well able to *delete* them. I imagine that
> if the other user had actually been someone else this might be a
> disaster for him — is there a way to prevent unauthorized users from
> deleting files? I mean I know related permissions can be set in the
> Windows file properties, but afterwards it only took me (using my default
> user without read access) to "take ownership" of the file again, and although I still I couldn't read it, I could very well **delete** it...*

> *Info just in case it surprisingly matters: the used (EFS encryption-) test files and EFS certificate im-/export happened via a
> Bitlocker-protected USB drive used under both test user accounts).*